# Bundled js link gets a 404 error for Orchard Module

Tags: http-status-code-404, bundle, orchardcms

Use 1.10 Orchard CMS and want to use System.Web.Optimization to use bundle. In fact I want convert html template for angular to script (to push template into $templateCache).

So I do

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var templates = new Bundle("~/bundles/templates/jt.CommonControls")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Modules/Jt.Framework/Scripts/CommonControls", "*.html", true);
        templates.Transforms.Add(new TemplatesTransform());
        bundles.Add(templates);
    }
}
```

and i do

```
public class ModuleInitializer : IOrchardShellEvents
{
    public void Activated()
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

and in view

```
<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/templates/jt.CommonControls")"></script>
```

Bundle created (all parts of code executed), i see it in debugger, everything is Ok and TemplatesTransform work correctly. And Url on the rendered page is good, BUT when browser request js by the url as a result i have 404 error.

Interesting thing is that I found solution for the problem some months ago (i have working orchard project with bundle), but cant remember what exactly i have done for it. Try to compare source codes (in fact last project is almost the same as working projct) but dont solve problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed my answer, it was wrong and I don't know what the correct one is, sorry.

Comment: There are two approaches possible here: Either use a custom gulp pipeline to package your templates into a complete app.js - bundle.
Or use the existing [assets pipeline](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Assets-pipeline/) of orchard to bundle your templates.